# how to prevent if statements from repeating in a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am working on a project, that has several if statements inside of 2 for loops.  What I am trying to do is have each if statement execute only once when it is true
Here is my code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                if (PokerCard[k] == two[i])
                {
                    PokerTwo++;
                }
                if (PokerTwo == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == three[i])
                {
                    PokerThree++;
                }
                if (PokerThree == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == four[i])
                {
                    PokerFour++;
                }
                if (PokerFour == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == five[i])
                {
                    PokerFive++;
                }
                if (PokerFive == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == six[i])
                {
                    PokerSix++;
                }
                if (PokerSix == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == seven[i])
                {
                    PokerSeven++;
                }
                if (PokerSeven == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == eight[i])
                {
                    PokerEight++;
                }
                if (PokerEight == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == nine[i])
                {
                    PokerNine++;
                }
                if (PokerNine == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == ten[i])
                {
                    PokerTen++;
                }
                if (PokerTen == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == jack[i])
                {
                    PokerJack++;
                }
                if (PokerJack == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == queen[i])
                {
                    PokerQueen++;
                }
                if (PokerQueen == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == king[i])
                {
                    PokerKing++;
                }
                if (PokerKing == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (PokerCard[k] == ace[i])
                {
                    PokerAce++;
                }
                if (PokerAce == 2)
                {
                    cash = cash + 10;
                    winnings = winnings + 10;
                    Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                    Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                    PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Winner.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see when an if statement is true it will add 10 to winnings, but I only want it to do that one time, so when it goes back through the loop it wont run that same if statement again, but maybe another one if that one becomes true.  Also I tried using a return at the bottom of the if statement, which works to an extent, but that will only allow one if statement to execute, and with the project I am working on I sometimes need it to go through two of the if statements.  removing the return will have it go through more if statements, but also run the same one multiple times, which I don't want.
any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have some sort of a flag like statementExecuted = False and when it goes inside the if statement change it to statementExecuted = True, and your condition should be something like if(PokerTwo == 2 && statementExecuted == False)

Answer (score 1):

if u want to execute each if only once for each iteration of 'i' then you should declare counter for each if; initialize all with 0 after outer loop statement and increment respective counter after each if statement execution.
For example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
         c1=0;
         c2=0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            if (PokerCard[k] == two[i] && c1==0)
            {
                PokerTwo++;
                c1++;
            }
            if (PokerTwo == 2 && c2==0)
            {
                cash = cash + 10;
                winnings = winnings + 10;
                Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
                Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
                PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
                Winner.Visible = true;
                c2++;
             }
           }
          }
```

And also remove return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your code clearly needs a `strategy` pattern.

Since I'm not aware of your business logic, I'll be using generic names for the classes/interfaces; please adjust those to your needs.
Another assumption I'll be making in order to ease up the code is that all properties in your code can be accessed from another class. Again, adjust it to your code.

Now, on to the code.
Declare an interface for the strategy:

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    bool IsApplicable(YourClass instance);

    void Apply(YourClass instance);
}
```

Now, for each `if` statement in your code create a class that implements `IStrategy`:

```
public class PokerTwoStrategy : IStrategy
{
    public bool IsApplicable(YourClass instance)
    {
        return instance.PokerTwo == 2;
    }

    public void Apply(YourClass instance)
    {
        instance.cash = cash + 10;
        instance.winnings = winnings + 10;
        instance.Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
        instance.Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
        instance.PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
        instance.Winner.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

After creating the strategies, in `YourClass` create a collection of `IStrategy` instances and in your method iterate over that collection and apply the strategy that can be applied:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IStrategy> _strategies;

    // Inject the strategies using DI container or build them manually
    public YourClass(IEnumerable<IStrategy> strategies)
    {
        _strategies = strategies;
    }

    public void YourMethod()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                _strategies.Where(s=>s.IsApplicable(this))
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(s => s.Apply(this));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now although you have introduced more types your code is more maintainable and easier to read/understand.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help,

Set a flag variable to a default value say 0 inside your if which will check if flag is 0 then only run the required statements , and inside this block itself set the flag variable to non-zero value this restrict block to be executed only once in coming iterations as well if block get's executed

Example

```
Block1_Flag=0
continue_run=0
//Statement_Block1
while(condition){
{
if(Block1_Flag == 0)
{
//so this bolck executed one so need to execute this again hence set Flag to 1 or any other number other then 1
Flag = 1
continue_run = 1
}
if(continue_run == 0){
return 
}
}
```

consider this as a generic logic which you can apply to the problem

Answer (score 0):

So I have a few suggestions to clean up your code.

First, use an array for your card counts, instead of `PokerTwo`, `PokerThree`, etc. This will let you replace all of those 13 `if` statements with a single loop, since it looks like the action is the same for every rank.

Second, assuming you store your cards as `int`s, from 0-51, you can use `PokerCard / 4` to get the suit and `PokerCard % 13` to get the rank (assuming you sort by suit first, then rank. If you sort by rank then suit, use `PokerCard % 4` and `PokerCard / 13`). Now you can get rid of the outer `for` loop, and also the `two`, `three`, etc. arrays.

Third, since you only want to run each `if` statement once, move them outside the main loop, so you only check once after you're done counting, rather than after each card.

This reduces your code to something like

```
var CardCount = new int[13];

for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
{
    CardCount[PokerCard[k] % 13]++;
}
for (int c = 0; c < 12; c++)
{
    if (CardCount[c] >= 2)
    {
        //do winning stuff
    }
}
```

That's a lot easier to manage.

Comment: Hello just want to thank everyone for there help, as everything has been helpful.  I did get it to work like I wanted, but I also do like the way you have it with so much less code.  I am actually not using ints.  I am pulling cards from a file folder, so In other words PokerCard[k] is actually a string.  This is being written in a windows application, so sadly that doesn't work, but if you can show me another way of doing it very little code with it being a string.  I was trying to think of another way, but couldn't come across anything.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to pull the cards from a file folder? 

The easiest way, off the top of my head, is to write some code to parse the strings and turn them into `int`s. It's usually best to store data in the simplest format possible, and `int`s are a lot simpler than strings.

At the very least, since all those code blocks are the same, just keep a running track of the number of wins you have, and then run the winning code in a loop at the end, counting the number of total wins.

Comment: There being called from a file folder, because there jpeg images. Thanks

Comment: What you should do is store `PokerCard[k]` as an `int`, then store the filenames in an array, and call it like this `CardFileName[PokerCard[k]]`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, without trying to figure out what your trying to do exactly, I can answer your question, albeit not the "right" answer, it is also not a wrong answer.
(I would **strongly** advise a different algorithm/approach than you are using - a rethink of the way you are solving this problem, it just doesn't look right, to much repeated code, unnecessary branches and will be very hard to maintain etc, I digress..)

**To answer your question literally;**

The easiest method would be to just add a check if that if statement has been executed. (*I am assuming you dont want to fire the "if" statements more than once while you are inside the outer for loop. I am also assuming you **do** intend the coupled if statements (incrementation) to execute more than once*).

```
// I'm assuming this code adds winnings for any pairs of cards found?
var PairedWinFlags = new bool[13]; // 13 cards

// Your outer loop
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        ...
        if (PokerCard[k] == two[i])
        {
            PokerTwo++;
        }
        if (PokerTwo == 2 && !PairedWinFlags[1]))
        {
            PairedWinFlags[1] = true; // Set this card flag to true
            cash = cash + 10;
            winnings = winnings + 10;
            Cash.Text = Convert.ToString(cash);
            Winnings.Text = Convert.ToString(winnings);
            PairWin.BackColor = Color.Red;
            Winner.Visible = true;
            return;
        }
        ...

        // ... Do the same for all other card types

        if (PokerAce == 2 && !PairedWinFlags[0]))
        {
            PairedWinFlags[0] = true;
        ...

        if (PokerQueen == 2 && !PairedWinFlags[11]))
        {
            PairedWinFlags[11] = true;
        ...
    }
}
```

Honestly, I would advise against this solution if you ever want to keep this code and possibly maintain/understand it. If so, you should start commenting through your code meaningfully - and maybe ask a question such as "*how do I count pairs of integers in an array?*"

Any way good luck :)